# Is there any JSON function in postgreSQL for append new key-value pair in existing JSON array

Tags: json, postgresql

My existing JSON array looks like this:

```
[{     "name": "XYZ",
        "Role": "Software Engineer"
    },
    {
        "name": "ABC",
        "Role": "BackEnd Developer"
    }]
```

Now, If I want to add new key-value as

```
{ "name": "pqr", "Role": "Tester" }
```

The output needs to display as

```
[{     "name": "XYZ",
        "Role": "Software Engineer"
    },
    {
        "name": "ABC",
        "Role": "BackEnd Developer"
    },
    {
         "name": "PQR",
          "Role": "Tester" 
   }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data type of the column was `JSONB` instead of `JSON`, then you could use `jsonb_insert()` function for DB version 9.6+ within a SELECT statement :

```
SELECT jsonb_insert( jsdata, 
                     array[jsonb_array_length(jsdata)::text],
                     '{ "name": "pqr", "Role": "Tester" }'::jsonb
                     )
  FROM t
 WHERE ID = <a sample scalar value>
```

or within an UPDATE statement :

```
UPDATE t
   SET jsdata = jsonb_insert( jsdata, 
                              array[jsonb_array_length(jsdata)::text],
                             '{ "name": "pqr", "Role": "Tester" }'::jsonb
                            )
 WHERE ID = <a sample scalar value>
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b887204a6a5551fd9438567d83c1858a)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

It the column only contains the (JSON) array you can use the concatenation operator:

```
select the_column || '{ "name": "pqr", "Role": "Tester" }'
from the_table;
```

If you want to actually change the data in the table, use that expression in an UPDATE statement:

```
update the_table
   set the_column = the_column || '{ "name": "pqr", "Role": "Tester" }'
where ....
```